# sample code for using mongoDB for storing user information and comments in an android application

Tags: android, mongodb, database

i need to use mongoDb as backend database for storing user information such as username and password. User can provide feedback on the application etc . Can anyone provide with sample code for using mongodb as backend database in an android application

Comment: why mongoDb? Android supports sqlite only.

Comment: but sqlite dnt allow access to update on remote database. i want all comments of customers on database located on mongolab.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't run MongoDB natively on Android.

You could however build a web service application with MongoDB for storage, and call methods on this webservice from your Android application.

Comment: i guess mongodb provide ready made API for connecting to database on mongolab.com. is there any way i can use that directly??

Comment: Mongolab is a hosted instance of mongodb

Comment: Google is your friend here.